# Clojure re-find reg-ex OR

Tags: clojure

I've been trying to get a simple reg-ex working in Clojure to test a string for some SQL reserved words (select, from, where etc.) but just can't get it to work:

```
(defn areserved? [c]
  (re-find #"select|from|where|order by|group by" c))
```

(I split a string by spaces then go over all the words)

Help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**: My first goal (after only reading some examples and basic Clojure materials) is to parse a string and return for each part of it (i.e. words) what "job" they have in the statement (a reserved word, a string etc.).

What I have so far:

```
(use '[clojure.string :only (join split)])

(defn isdigit? [c]
  (re-find #"[0-9]" c))

(defn isletter? [c]
  (re-find #"[a-zA-Z]" c))

(defn issymbol? [c]
  (re-find #"[\(\)\[\]!\.+-><=\?*]" c))

(defn isstring? [c]
  (re-find #"[\"']" c))

(defn areserved? [c]
  (if (re-find #"select|from|where|order by|group by" c)
      true
      false))

(defn what-is [token]
  (let [c (subs token 0 1)]
    (cond
      (isletter? c)  :word
      (areserved? c) :reserved
      (isdigit? c)   :number
      (issymbol? c) :symbol
      (isstring? c) :string)))

(defn checkr [token]
  {:token token
   :type (what-is token)})

(defn goparse [sql-str]
  (map checkr (.split sql-str " ")))
```

Thanks for all the help guys! it's great to see so much support for such a relatively new language (at least for me :) )

Comment: If you split by spaces then it's meaningless to inclued "order by" and "group by" in your pattern.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate on how it doesn't work? In case your function matches too eagerly (e.g. `(areserved? "whereto")` you may want to use `re-matches` instead. Or if it's too case-sensitive (e.g. `(areserved? "WHERE")`) you may want to wrap `(?i:...)` around your regex group. In any case reading the docs for [Clojure regex](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/re-find) and [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) helps.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you want exactly, but here's a couple of variations to coerce your first regex match to a boolean:

```
(defn areserved? [c]
  (string?
    (re-find #"select|from|where|order by|group by"c)))

(defn areserved? [c]
  (if (re-find #"select|from|where|order by|group by"c)
      true
      false))
```

#### UPDATE in response to question edit:

Thanks for posting more code. Unfortunately there are a number of issues here that we could
try to address by patching your existing code in a simplistic and naïve fashion, but it will
only get you so far, before you hit the next problem with this single iteration approach.

@alex is correct, that your `areserved?` method will fail to match `order by` if you have already
split your string by white space. That said, a simple fix is to treat `order` and `by` as separate keywords (which they are, even though they always appear together).

The next issue is that the `areserved?` function will match keywords in a string, but you are dispatching it against a character in the `what-is` function. You nearly always get a match in your `cond` for `isletter?`, so you will everything is marked as a 'word'.

All in all, it looks like you are trying to do too much work in a single application of `map`.

I'm not sure if you are just doing this for fun to play with Clojure (which is admirable - keep going!), in which case, maybe it doesn't matter if you press on with this simple parsing approach... you'll definitely learn something; but if you would like to take it further and parse SQL more successfully, then I would suggest that you may find it helpful to to read a little on **[Lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)**, **[Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)** and building **[Abstract Syntax Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)** (AST).

Brian Carper has written about using the **[Java parser generator "ANTLR" from Clojure](http://briancarper.net/blog/554/antlr-via-clojure)** - it's a few years old, but might be worth looking at.

You also might be able to get some transferrable ideas from [this chapter from the F# programming book on lexing and parsing SQL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing#Extended_Example%3a_Parsing_SQL).

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for not clarifying, I'm trying to write a simple program that will parse/validate a string from the user. As SQL can't be tested fully via regular expressions I'm trying to just take a simple query line ("select this from that" for example) and check what classification each word in it meets (reserved word, digit, string, word etc).

It's my first attempt at Clojure and I'm having a problem with the regular expression matching.

Thanks!

Comment: @RX this should work for the problem as (vaguely) stated. If you're still having trouble, then try posting a more complete example, with test data, to illustrate how you're calling the function along with expected vs. observed results.

Comment: @RX I took a guess at what you wanted, but clearly missed. Could you add a couple of example inputs with expected outputs? I'm sure the Clojure community will step up and help, as soon as we know exactly what you want :-)

Comment: Updated my post, should've done that at the beginning already. Thanks everyone!